# bash shell array output range to csv

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

Is there an easier way to do the below? I am reading in a large cvs file and want to only display ranges on the index per line and output back into a csv format.

```
while  IFS=$',' read -r -a myArray
do
    echo ${myArray[44]},${myArray[45]},${myArray[46]},${myArray[47]},${myArray[48]},${myArray[65]},${myArray[66]},${myArray[67]}
done < $SHEET
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the substring operator with array parameter expansion:

```
while IFS=, read -r -a myArray
do
    ( IFS=,; echo "${myArray[*]:44:5},${myArray[*]:65:3}" )
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $65, $66, $67}' "$SHEET"
```

We set the **Input Field Separator (FS)** and **Output Field Separator (OFS)** to `,` so that output will be in `csv` format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is tailor-made job of awk. Use this awk command:

```
awk -F"," '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", 
            $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $65, $66, $67)}' $SHEET
```